# Basic Chrome extension breaking sites HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for the relatively broad title... So I have a pretty basic chrome extension with a Popup(html\js) and a content page.

Basically all the extension does is put a button on the popup page that when clicked sends a message to the content script to check all check boxes on the page. The code is pretty basic but it is breaking stuff like dropdown menus and general formatting.

Here is all of my code, like I said it's not much. Any ideas what could be going on?

Content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if( request.message === "toggle_checkboxes" ) {         
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
          if(this.checked)
            this.checked = false;
          else
            this.checked = true;
        });        
      }                         
      else{
        //alert("nothing caught, here is the message:" + request.messgae);
      }
    }
  );
```

popup.js

```
function toggle_checkboxes() {    
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "toggle_checkboxes"});
 });
}

document.getElementById('toggle_checkboxes').addEventListener('click', toggle_checkboxes);
```

Comment: I don't think anything you've posted could affect the original DOM layout. When you look at the elements in DevTools, do you see any changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking dropdown menus"? You mean `<select>` tags don't work?

Comment: Maybe you're injecting jQuery into the page itself via script element, which you shouldn't do.